# Nginx proxied site can't find static image file on site

Tags: nginx

I have a jpg file staying on the media subdirectory of the root path and I use Nginx to serve the file. But when I open the browser it says this in the developer console.

> http://localhostmedia/bg.jpg Failed to load resource: A server with
>   the specified hostname could not be found.

I don't know what went wrong. There is no errors in Nginx logs. I am deploying it on my local server not on the internet. Here is my Nginx settings:

```
upstream ws_upstream {
    server 127.0.0.1:8888;
    keepalive 64;
}

server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80 default_server;
    #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/local/share/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name ws_server;


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @my_upstream;
    }

    location = /index.html {
        try_files /index.html $uri/ =404;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg)$ {
        root /usr/local/share/html/media;
        expires 10d;
    } 

    location @my_upstream {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://ws_upstream;
        proxy_read_timeout 240s;
    }

}
```

What should I change to my file?

**UPDATE:**

Using `curl -i http://localhost` will show the source code of the javascript file that my `index.html` references.

My folder structure for client side in the root path:

```
/usr/local/share/html
    -- index.html
    -- main.js
    media
       -- bg.jpg
```

Here is my `index.html` file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no, email=no" />
  <meta name="renderer" content="webkit">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
  <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
  <meta name="screen-orientation" content="portrait">
  <meta name="x5-orientation" content="portrait">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
  <title>My project</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding: 0;}
    *:focus {
      outline: none;
    }
    html,body,#cas{width:100%;height:100%;overflow: hidden;}
    .input {
      border:1px solid #1099bb;
      border:none;
      padding-left: 14px;
      padding-right: 14px;
      border-radius:18px;
      -moz-border-radius:18px;
      -webkit-border-radius:18px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/main.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Here are some most recent access logs:

```
2017/08/16 12:58:49 [error] 1883#0: *3 open() "/usr/local/share/html/media/media/bg.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: ::1, server: ws_server, request: "GET /media/bg.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/"

2017/08/16 13:12:06 [error] 2111#0: *5 open() "/usr/local/share/htmlindex.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: ::1, server: ws_server, request: "GET /__webpack_hmr HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/"
```

Comment: Look in the Nginx access log. It will probably be something simple like the URL it's trying to load not quite matching the required URL - for example in your error message there no slash between "localhost" and "media"

Comment: @Tim The access log has nothing special. It only displays "GET / HTTP/1.1" followed by some browser infomation.

Comment: The status code and any messages in the logs are important. I'd like to see a "curl -i" (including the curl command line), any interesting parts of the curl output or all of it if you're not sure, and the matching Nginx access log. Please edit your question rather than replying in comments. Based on your comment saying "it just says GET /" I think your request is malformed, it's not hitting the server.

Comment: can you share the index.html file snippet where it access the bg.jpg or maybe the css where it request it ?

Comment: @Tim Thanks I have updated my question. I have noticed there is a 200 status code of websocket protocol. That's another problem I had.

Comment: Random logs aren't helpful. The curl is good, but it needs to correlate to a specific log entry. Then you need to find the jpg request in the html source and make that request exactly as the html specifies. You're not making it easy to help you.

Comment: @Tim Sorry I don't understand. What kind of logs do I need? These are not random logs. My app has only one page and only one button. When I access the homepage it makes one request. When I click the button it makes another one to the server. This works totally fine in my development environment. It just stops working when I deploy it behind a Nginx server.

Comment: Since there are no requests for jpg files in the log, and your error message is saying a jpg isn't found, the request isn't making it to the server. Since you seem unwilling or unable to provide sufficient information to help answer your question I'm voting to close.

Comment: @Tim What? Why do you say I am unwilling or unable to provide sufficient information? I've never written a question longer than this one. I just don't know what information need to be disclosed. I've shown people my Nginx.conf and my index.html and the logs. What more now?

Comment: I suggest you go back and read all my comments again. I've said the same thing three or four times but you haven't investigated, or at least you haven't reported back. Ways to look at this would be the browser debug tools, seeing what request is made, to where, because it's not hitting your server.

Comment: @Tim OK I think I misunderstood your comments. Now I have updated the relevant logs. It seems the urls are malformed. I have updated my `Nginx.conf` file too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jpeg request is adding media twice, because you've specified it in the URL and the config. To fix the problem with the jpeg change this

```
location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg)$ {
  root /usr/local/share/html/media; # remove media
  expires 10d;
}
```

to

```
location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg)$ {
  root /usr/local/share/html;
  expires 10d;
}
```

I'm not 100% sure about the index.html error. I suspect you're missing a slash somewhere or the request your browser is sending isn't quite right. Based on the answer I've given above and that clue perhaps you can have a think and see if you can come up with something.

Comment: Oh I should just remove the entire `root` line because I have already had a `root` path above. But I don't understand why Nginx couldn't find my static files without configuring a location like this.

Comment: Yes that should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be found because your pointing to the wrong path/url it should be like

> http://localhost/static/bg.jpg

but your pointing to

> http://localhostmedia/bg.jpg

so the browser will try to connect to a host named

> localhostmedia

Comment: I thought `/static/` is just a virtual path. I know the path is wrong. But more importantly, how to fix this? Even if I delete the `location /static/` block it is still the same result.

Comment: try to change "proxy_pass http://snake_ws_upstream;" to "              proxy_pass http://snake_ws_upstream / ;

Comment: Sorry it should be "proxy_pass my_upstream;" But anyway if I add a slash at the end Nginx will say can't use reg_ex in named location or something like that.